# Bijection for Catalan Number

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

[image]

How can I show that this maps to

[image]

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Start at any vertex and go around the circle clockwise. Write down a left parenthesis, `(`, the first time you come to an endpoint of a chord, and a right parenthesis, `)`, when you come to the other endpoint. Starting at the leftmost vertex of your first picture, for instance, you’d write the sequence `(())()`. Show that this gives you a bijection with the set of valid strings of $n$ pairs of parentheses.